# Why do you say "square" in "Be there or be square"?

Tags: popular-refrains

I've known the saying

> Be there or be square!

for a long time, but never really understood - why "square"? Where does that come from? Why not

> Be there or be rectangular!

:-)

Comment: Yes, why not 'rectangular', though perhaps in a different kind of sentence.

Comment: **square** (adj.) c.1300, "containing four equal sides and right angles," from square (n.). Meaning "honest, fair," is first attested 1560s; that of "straight, direct" is from 1804. Sense of "old-fashioned" is 1944, U.S. jazz slang, said to be from shape of a conductor's hand gestures in a regular four-beat rhythm. (Square-toes meant nearly the same thing in 1771, from a style of shoes then fallen from fashion.) Squaresville is attested from 1956. Online Etymology Dictionary, hence general reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about "a square plus b square"?

Comment: Because 'rectangular' doesn't rhyme with 'there'?

Comment: @Kris That's a *squared*, participle

Comment: Because if you're not a square, you're a round!

Answer (score 8):

***[square](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square)***: conventional, boring.
(*slang*) A socially conventional person; typically associated with the 1950s
*Why do you always wear a tie? Don't be such a **square**!*

[*be there or be square*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_there_or_be_square):

> (idiomatic, US, UK, humorous) Used to encourage someone to go somewhere.
>   *There's a huge party on Saturday night; **be there or be square**.*

Comment: Incidentally, in carpenter's and mason's lingo, to *be square* **is** to *be rectangular* -- go figure!

Comment: 'Square' in that sense is extremely dated now. It went out of fashion in about 1960.

Comment: It is an important word in Freemasonry. 'Are you on the square' is, I'm informed, a coded inquiry as to whether the other party is a freemason.

Comment: @WS anything by way of 'further reading'?

Comment: You could look at this for starters: http://freemasonry.bcy.ca/fiction/vernacular.html